# segmentation fault on wrap of realloc function

Tags: c, runtime-error, realloc

I've written a wrap of a `realloc()` function in C, but the program gives me segmentation fault.
The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access. Hint: address points to the zero page. Is it a dereferencing of NULL pointer on line p[i] = i * 2;?

```
int reallocmem(int *p,size_t newsize){
    void *q;
    q = realloc(p,newsize);
    if(q != NULL){
        p = q;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    int *p = 0x0;
    if(!reallocmem(p,10*sizeof(int))){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not reallocate memory\n");

    }           
    int i;
    int size = 10;
    for(i = 0;i<size;i++){
        p[i] = i * 2;
    }

    for(i = 0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\n",p[i]);
    }
    free(p);

}
```

Comment: changes made to `p` does not reflect after the `reallocmem()` call. you need to pass a double pointer

Comment: regarding: `if(!reallocmem(p,10*sizeof(int))){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not reallocate memory\n");

    }`  do not continue to exec the program if the function: `reallocmem()` fails

Comment: regarding: `int *p = 0x0;
    if(!reallocmem(p,10*sizeof(int))){` to change the contents of a pointer, need t pass the address of the pointer, similar to: `int *p = 0x0;
    if(!reallocmem(&p,10*sizeof(int))){`  and the function: `reallocmem()` needs to be modified to access through that parameter to the original pointer

Answer (score 3):

The value of `p` in `main` hasn't been changed after calling the function `reallocmem`, so a segmentation fault happened because the program tries to dereference the NULL pointer.

To pass a pointer as an argument and change it, we need to pass a pointer of the pointer:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int reallocmem(int **p, size_t newsize) {
  void *q;
  q = realloc(*p, newsize);
  if (q != NULL) {
    *p = q;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
int main(void) {
  int *p = 0x0;
  if (!reallocmem(&p, 10 * sizeof(int))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not reallocate memory\n");
    free(p);
    return 0;
  }
  int i;
  int size = 10;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    p[i] = i * 2;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
  }
  free(p);
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cfd538j7e)

---

The C program passes every argument by value, if you add `printf` statement in your code, you will find that the `p` in `reallocmem` have a different address with the `p` in `main`, so in order to change the `p` in `main`, we need to pass the address of `p`(pointer to pointer) but not the value of `p`. Or the local copy of `p` in `reallocmem` has been changed, but it won't affect the caller function `main`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int reallocmem(int *p, size_t newsize) {
  printf("%p\n", &p);
  void *q;
  q = realloc(p, newsize);
  if (q != NULL) {
    p = q;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
int main(void) {
  int *p = 0x0;
  printf("%p\n", &p);
  if (!reallocmem(p, 10 * sizeof(int))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not reallocate memory\n");
  }
  int i;
  int size = 10;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    p[i] = i * 2;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
  }
  free(p);
}
```

Comment: thank you! So in the original code the pointer wasn't affected that's why it was giving segmentation fault? Because I was trying to dereferencing p,wich was 0x0?

Comment: @victor0x3E7 Excatlly! I will update the answer.

Comment: Upon the error of reallocmem(), you should exit from the program and not continue. Here you merely display "Could not reallocate memory" and you continue to run...

Comment: @RachidK. Thank you so much for pointing out that, I have fixed it.

Comment: Moreover realloc() does not deallocate the memory space when it returns NULL. So, when realloc(p, ...) fails, p still point on a valid memory space if it was not NULL before the call. To avoid memory leaks, some action should be taken in the error case : possibly free(p).

Answer (score 0):

On top of previous answers, to avoid memory leaks in the error branches, action must be taken when `realloc()` returns NULL as according to the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc):

> If realloc() fails, the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

So, when `realloc(p, ...)` returns NULL, the error branch should free what was pointed by 'p' (if it was not NULL before the call) when it is not planed to use 'p' any more...